# can't move mouse on Roblox

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui, roblox

I tried out two different libraries for this but ran into the same issue.

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100,100)
pydirectinput.moveTo(100,100)
```

The code works fine outside of Roblox but whenever I run it with Roblox as the active window I have to slightly move my mouse for python to move to the location I want

Comment: You may need to manually set/get roblox to be the active window.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand your comment I said that this issue occurs when Roblox is the active window

Comment: All I'm saying is Roblox may be taking control over pythons precedence. It is worth a try imho.

Comment: So you don't want Roblox to be the active window? Don't even think its possible to automate Roblox without it being the active window

Answer (score 1):

I will not question your motives...

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, WORD
from math import floor
emptyLong = ctypes.c_ulong()

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", DWORD),
                ("dwFlags", DWORD),
                ("time", DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))]

class KeybdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", WORD),
                ("wScan", WORD),
                ("dwFlags", DWORD),
                ("time", DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", DWORD),
                ("wParamL", WORD),
                ("wParamH", WORD)]

class InputList(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ("mi", MouseInput),
        ("ki", KeybdInput),
        ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("inputList", InputList)]

MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001
MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
def move(x, y, relative=False): # MOVE MOUSE TO (X, Y)
    mouseFlag = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE

    if not relative:
        mouseFlag |= MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE
        x = floor(x/1920 * 65535) # ASSUMING COORDINATES ARE BASED ON 1920 x 1080 RESOLUTION
        y = floor(y/1080 * 65535)
        
    inputList = InputList()
    inputList.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, mouseFlag, 0, ctypes.pointer(emptyLong))

    windowsInput = Input(emptyLong, inputList)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(windowsInput), ctypes.sizeof(windowsInput))
```

just a little bit of C. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)